# Are 1-1/4" screws enough for cement board if I shim the studs with 1/2" shims?

Tags: screws, cement-board

Due to an offset between the plumbing and the shower drain I need to float the wall on the short side of the shower base with like 3/4-1/2" so I am using top to bottom shims. I am not sure if the screws that I have ([1-1/4" Durock screws](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/cgc-durock-screws-for-durock-cement-board-1-1-4-in-200-screws/1001341803)) fit the purpose.

Can I still use them? (They will be 1/2" in cement board, 3/8" in the shim and 3/8" in the stud.)

Just to play safe I bought [1-5/8" screws](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/backer-on-1-5-8-inch-backer-on-serrated-head-star-drive-cement-board-screw-140pcs/1001157616) that are from a different manufacturer. I'm not sure if I can still use them with USG Durock cement board.

It seems that for both it is essential to have a larger head, coarse thread, resistant to corrosion and sharp enough to penetrate the cement board which is stronger than the drywall.

Comment: If you're really concerned about the diameter of the screw (from a comment below), why not return the 1-5/8" screws and buy the brand you're comfortable with in the length you need? Also, unless you've already opened/used some of the shorter ones, you could probably return those, as well.

Comment: I don't see any mention of screw diameter.

Comment: FYI, you could also just use coated deck screws in pairs if you wanted even more penetration. That's how drywall was done using nails in the old days. It's not rocket surgery. :)

Comment: I did not open any of the two boxes. The problem seems to be that they are the only two options available in HomeDepot Canada in Toronto

Comment: I thought the head shape and size is essential in this case. Seeing how fragile the cement board is I am going to have to test how it behaves with these screws, my first impression without testing is that they might crush the cement board, I might need to adjust the drill to tighten to a specific pressure only
The deck screws might have a too small head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1-5/8 cement board screws are much better for this purpose, as they'll go through your 3/8" shims and still have 3/4" in the stud. Even if your shims are fastened securely to the studs it's much better to have the cement board securely fastened to the studs with its own fasteners and not relying on the shim-to-stud fastener.

Comment: what I am not sure is if the two types of screws are compatible

Comment: Any coated cement board screw is fine.

Comment: these 1-5/8" screws are thicker ..should I predrill in place (both the cement board and the shim) before I put the screws in ? I am afraid that they might split the shims

Comment: @MiniMe - predrilling... that seems like another question.

Comment: No. Well, it won't hurt, but cement board is soft and porous. Unless you're having issues along an edge, the self-drilling point should do the job. Split shims aren't actually a problem.

Comment: You can pre-drill but keep in mind cement board eats drill bits for breakfast, they will dull very quickly. Cement backer board screws are designed to be self-drilling. If your shims are prone to splitting it's even more important to depend on the stud and not the shim to carry the weight of the cement board.

Comment: We're getting off topic, but yes cement board is hard to work with if you're not used to it. It's sold in 1/2" sheets for walls to match drywall thickness and 1/4" sheets for floors. Concrete isn't very strong at these thicknesses but it is still heavy so they mix it with something like styrofoam beads to reduce weight a bit. Since it is so brittle they coat each side with a plastic mesh that gives it some bending strength, otherwise it would be impossible to transport or position.